# How to add column in data frame based on >= condition in another column/ Histogram densities over a particular range?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data as follows

```
 > mids

   x      y
 1 33 0.0020
 2 35 0.0075
 3 37 0.0240
 4 39 0.0725
 5 41 0.1355
 6 43 0.1325
 7 44 0.0900
 8 47 0.0300
 9 49 0.0060
```

I want to sum the y- coords for when x-coords are more than or equal to 44 so the last 3 numbers in y column?

Basically the data is in a histogram so if anyone know how to add the densities of the histogram above a certain x-value that would be great too.

Thanks.

Comment: sum(mids$y[which(mids$x >= 44)]) should do the job :)

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try these.

```
library(dplyr)
mids%>%filter(x>=44)%>%summarise(sum(y))
```